# Problem splitting "matrix"-string into actual matrix in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to enter a matrix into a single cell (lots of variable => tedious to enter one entry/cell)  i chose the format x_1, y_1; x_2, y_2; ... and would like to split this up so I can access them easily for various functions. My first idea was to firstly split them up with the ; delimiter to get a row of x_i, y_i cells and then split that row into two rows, one with x_i and one with y_i.  The first part worked out but I'm having trouble doing the second part effectively.

first formula: (in 'split 1' sheet)
`=split(data!F2; ";")`

second formula:
`=transpose(split(filter('split 1'!B1:Z1; len('split 1'!B1:Z1)); "," ) )`

The second formula only works for the first cell but doesnt give me anything else, i tried adding arrayformula() to it but it still doesnt work, what am I doing wrong? (I know I could just apply the function to a single cell and then copy it to the other cells but that seems like a very bad solution that easily breaks)

Also, I currently store the rows in separate sheets, I don't really need the data I just want to put them into a few functions. Is there a way to do this in a single cell so I just can write `=function(expression for the split)`?

#EDIT
Im trying to make a recipe calculator (like myfitnesspal) using sheets, heres a link to an editable copy of it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hKVbnot6PSangmooprs7vMwrP5Txj5_ddMc9Xgowvs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your data or layout, and we don't know your end goal. I'm sure it is 100% clear to you what you are trying to do; but from "out here," we have no idea where you're going, so it's hard to know how to help you get there. The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to a spreadsheet set up to include some realistic data as well as the results you'd like to see (manually entered by you) where you'd like to see them. Just be sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Be sure to clearly explain your END goal as well, since I suspect that splitting entries into two paired rows is only an intermediate step toward that end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(G2; ";")); ",")))
```

[image]